# Flickering light outside front door

Tags: electrical

So I recently installed 6 ceiling LED lights with a Lutron dimmer switch in the living room. The power for the lutron switch feeds another switch (non lutron)for an outside lamp just outside the front door.
I just found out that the outside lamp (non-led) would flicker anytime the living room lights are on.

Before this, I thought it could be a faulty bulb, but every bulb I tried did the same thing, though at a different rate. Then I thought it must have been the dawn sensor on the lamp, but replacing the lamp didn't solve the issue. SO now that I know what causes the issue, how do I fix it? and what is really happening?

Comment: Can you measure the frequency of the flickering?

Comment: Yes, it's a very consistent 5 to 7 times per second and extremely annoying. 
Different wattage bulb will act differently but there is always flicker when the LED living rooms lights are on. Those are fine

Comment: temporarily bypass the Lutron dimmer switch so that the 6 ceiling lights are on

Comment: I'd try taking the dimmer out of the circuit, yes....

Comment: I strongly suspect some sort of miswiring, probably at the dimmer. Does it flicker even when the LED lights are off?

Comment: The outside light only flickers when the the lutron switch powering the LEDs is ON.

Comment: I bypassed the Lutron dimmer switch and there is no flicker. All lights are on full power and the outside light is no longer flickering. Should I try a different dimmer? Or is the outside lamp which has a night/movement sensor not playing well with having a Lutron dimmer in the circuit?

Comment: Are all the devices that are dimmed by the dimmer dimmerable?

Comment: Yes, all are dimmable LEDs.

Comment: I just swapped the Diva Lutron switch for a cheaper Leviton and did the trick. Thank you everybody for your input. Not sure why the Diva Lutron affected another switch/light on the same circuit but a different dimmer did the trick.

Comment: Glad to hear that you have it working. Curious to know if the outside light was flickering regardless whether the living room lights were full on or just dimmed?  I know there are different types of dimmers out there. Some dim by cutting off the early part of the voltage sine wave while others cut of the later part of the voltage sine wave and others reduce the peak voltage.